# DateFormatter in iOS belongs to view model or model or controller?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, mvvm, nsdateformatter

Can any one please do confirm that the DateFormatter in iOS(Swift) belongs to which level of architecture such as ViewModel or model or controller ??

Answer (score 2):

It should be at view model:

The ViewModel `encapsulates data/properties that the view can bind to and any validation logic and actions that can be performed`. Typically, the ViewModel interacts with the model by invoking methods in the model classes. **The ViewModel then provides data from the model in a form that the view can easily use**. In this pattern we are essentially taking the state of our app and putting it into a ViewModel.

Answer (score 2):

Basically any changes you make it to the model or get any data from model should go to viewModel. 
Hence you should have the dateformatter in the viewModel

Comment: can you add some detail info

Answer (score 2):

> ViewModel

it works as a mediator between the Model and the View, ViewModel provides the connection between the business logic and the view/view controller.

The view (UI) responds to user input by passing input data (defined by the model) to the viewModel. In turn, the ViewModel evaluates the input data and responds with an appropriate UI presentation according to business logic workflow. In addition, a view model will trigger all calls to send and receive data (using data managers) as well as any data manipulation to prepare it for being displayed in views.

you can find the complete answer in below following link

[MVVM vs MVC](https://medium.com/@piyush.dez/ios-architectures-5a19cd56edc2)

Answer (score 1):

You could have something like this:

```
enum FormatDateTimeType {
 case time
 case shortDate
}

extension Date {
 func string(_ formattedAs: FormatDateTimeType) {
     .......
 }
}
```

then your text componente should use the date 'string' func like this:

```
myTextField.text = myModel.date.string(.shortDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite the answers posted here we should take a bit deeper look into this this specific case. Date formatter is a tool to convert between date (a time stamp) and a visual representation of that time stamp as a string. In a sense this is a descriptor on how to present an information. In my opinion it is closer to for instance `font` which is usually on a view.

If you used your view model on multiple situations it would mean that you might need multiple different representations of this same data. For instance a same model may be used on table view cell to use date alone. Then pressing the cell may open a new screen representing the same model showing date and time or even age of the date.

From that perspective (not that I see it wrong) I would rather put date formatter on a view or on a view controller. Imaging a subclass of `UILabel` that exposes properties to `dateFormat` and `date` which is used to show date alone.

Another very important thing to know is that date formatters are extremely slow when initializing them. So if possible we try to have tools that hold our date formatters in static context where they may be reused. Some make tools like `DataTools.timeString(fromDate: myDate)` others extensions on `Date` to have `myDate.timeString`. Some even enumerate formatters resulting in `myDate.string(formattedAs: .time)`.

Using the last approach is probably best as you can then use your formats even as properties. Now you need to basically choose which looks more appropriate to you:

```
timeLabel.text = model.date.string(formattedAs: .time)
dateLabel.text = model.date.string(formattedAs: .shortDate)
```

or

```
timeLabel.text = model.dateStringFormattedAsTime
dateLabel.text = model.dateStringFormattedAsShortDate
```

So if you ask me the `DateFormatter` should be in some static context while even the format description should be as close to the view itself as possible.

Comment: I don't think comparison to the font property is appropriate for two reasons.  1) it's a property that has existed on views since before MVVM was a thing, and 2) it's necessary for the rendering of the view itself, which is absolutely the responsibility of the view.  A date formatter, on the other hand, is used to generate the string to be displayed, and is not involved at all in rendering that string.

Comment: In addition to my previous comment, witness the not-exactly-recent addition of `attributedText` (or whatever the property is called), which allows bundling the font information with the string itself.  This allows a view model object to specify exactly the rendering properties that you claim belong as part of the view.

Comment: @Avi They may not be exactly the same but your arguments completely invalid; 1 It makes no difference when was what created. Even if font was introduced later it would still be a property of a label. 2. DateFormat is necessary to draw (convert to string) date so in case of using as for instance described a subclass to show a date it is exactly as important as font.

Comment: @Avi attributed text was designed only to build more complex string which may have different fonts, colors, on different string ranges. They are by no chance connected to MVVM or any other modern procedure. And they should be by all cost avoided if possible due to their performance drain. Do not by any chance use attributed strings just to construct it in a model.

Comment: It does matter, because if MVVM had been the architecture-of-choice, the developers of `UIKit` might have made a different decision with respect to how a label's font is specified.  We can't know either way, so it's not valid to compare them.  I happen to think that the choice would be the same, because font is a necessary component of a label's purpose.

Comment: If you create a date-renderer-component, then it would make sense to have the format be part of the view.  However, a `UILabel` is a string renderer, not a date renderer.  The whole point of MVVM is to separate the how from the what.  The model gives the what and the label knows how.

Comment: @Avi `UILabel` is a string renderer. It is a subclass of `UIView` which is a whatever-renderer. A `DateLabel` may be a date renderer from what I care and may be a subclass of `UILabel`. "The model gives the what and the label knows how". Yes, model gives date and label knows how to render it. Not model gives label with information on how to present it. If your model for instance had 2 dates where a 3rd one must be created by taking an average of both then the model is responsible in computing that average. But not how the average is shown. For what we care it may be a slider that shows it.

Comment: Your answer supposes that a `DateRenderer` component should be created to satisfy the user's requirement, but it doesn't answer the question that was actually posed.

Comment: @Avi it does not. As described it should be as close to the view as possible or at least the property for it. As stated date formatters are best placed in a static context for reuse. Then the property as how the date should be formatted presented again needs to be as close to the view as possible because it is a representation property of the data, not data or data processing itself.

Comment: @Avi which as already said is closer to font or text color or any other property that changes the visual output of the same data.

Comment: The formatter belongs to the layer responsible for generating the content.  If one has a `DateLabel` that takes dates, then that component should have the formatter.  If one is using a general component such as `UILabel`, then some other class is generating content for that component.  In MVVM, that would be the view model.  The question of whether you should create a component for rendering dates is orthogonal.

Comment: @Avi also I do not see it wrong if you put it into model, it is what I meant in my answer by saying "not that I see it wrong". I definitely see this question as an interesting one and would not satisfy for as stubborn answer without looking into it deeply.

Comment: A formatter determines what the content _is_, not what it should look like.  That's my perspective, anyway.

Comment: @Avi this is exactly where I disagree. Date is the actual data, string is only used to show it. Without descriptor of shape of string it may not be presented as such the same way as it can not be without color, font... I do see your point though.

Comment: Of course the date is the actual data.  But the view model of MVVM is there precisely to mediate between the data (model) and the view.